# How to extend a fixed-length Python list by variable number of characters?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

(If someone can suggest a better title, by all means go ahead and edit).

Given a `list` *list1* whose exact length is unknown but for which it is known will always be less than or equal to 5, I'm looking to populate a separate empty `list` *list2*, of fixed length 5, with the values in *list1*, padding out with empty strings if the size of *list2* is less than 5.

e.g. if list1 = [1,2,3]

then list2 should be [1,2,3,'','']

and so on.

So:

```
if len(list1) < 5:
    list2.extend(list1)
    # at this point, I want to add the empty strings, completing the list of size 5
```

What's the neatest way of achieving this (determining how many empty strings to add)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
list2 = list1 + [''] * (5 - len(list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
extend_list = lambda list, len=5, fill_with='': map(lambda e1, e2: e1 if e2 is None else e2, [fill_with]*len, list)
print extend_list([1, 2, 3])
>>> [1, 2, 3, '', '']
print extend_list([1, 2], 3, '?')
>>> [1, 2, '?']
```